# Is it possible to send a keyboard event to a background script that's expecting user interaction? (Using 'read')

Tags: process, pipe

Ex:

```
$read &
[1] 15139

[1]+  Stopped    
$jobs -l
[1]+ 15139 Stopped (tty input) read
```

Answer (score 2):

Can easily be done with a fifo.

```
$ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/sh
read bar
echo got $bar in the read line

$ mkfifo foo
$ ./bar.sh < foo &
$ echo hello > foo 
$ got hello in the read line
[1]+  Done                    ./bar.sh < foo
$
```